# Add some parameters to a flash object via php

Tags: php

I have a challenge where I'm submitting data with flash objects (youtube vids).

I want to look in the string of this data to a) see if there's an object and then b) 1) add some parameters  inside the object and also 2) add the same attribute to the embed

So far I have...

```
// check if the content contains a youtube video... and that it doesn't have the opaque wmode
if(strstr($content, '<object')   &&  strstr($content != 'wmode="opaque"')) {


   // split the string after the object tag, and insert the <param tag

   // find the occurance of the <embed tag and insert the attribute

 }
```

Then I realised, what happens if the data contains 2 or more objects in the $content string (which its probable it will) ? So the solution needs some sort of looping function for each object that is in the $content var.

I'm thinking i need to

- count the number of times there is an object in the variable.
- loop through each and do the above code for each one -eek

Am I approaching this correctly? What do you think is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(preg_match_all('/<object(.*?)<\/object>/', $content, $matches)) {
   print_r ($matches);
}
```